# Panning on huge div

Tags: jquery, css, html, canvas

My plan is to have big div (4000px x 4000px) and inside smaller divs with phrases random positioned to that big div. User would see of course only portion of it at time. But when moving mouse for example on right side of browser window the view would pan slowly to right on that big div. And of course when moving mouse lower part of browser window it would pan down and upper right corner then it would pan upper right corner of that div.

On mobile (less than 600px) all those smaller divs should be just stacked on top of each other and use can just scroll up/downd traditionally.

Now my question should this be done with canvas or would it be possible do with HTML & jquery somehow? Or anyone know if there is some jquery lib that would have functionality like this?

Comment: I can't think of any jQuery library that does that but I'm pretty sure it can be done with HTML & jQuery. What's your code so far?

Comment: None yet. I'm just more asking direction where to go before I start to be honest because I'm not sure which would be ideal way to go. Yeah tried googling some jQuery lib but wasn't able to find but wasn't sure if i was googling with correct words

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is solving this in canvas where you only show a smaller area but in your code, the objects can appear basically everywhere, or keep it within the borders of 4000x4000 if you want.

You'll use two variables: offSetX and offSetY, which will change when the mouse tracks towards the edge of the canvas (left, right, up or down). When you paint things, you'll paint them with the x- and y- coordinates you have assigned to them, **MINUS** the offset-variables.

Se working example below.

**Note**, to save some CPU, perform a check to see if the object you're about to paint is even visible in the current viewing window, if not, then don't draw it.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

c.height = 300;
c.width = 500;

var offSetX = 0;
var offSetY = 0;
var movingLeft = false;
var movingRight = false;
var movingDown = false;
var movingUp = false;   

//Mouse event to see what is going on.
c.addEventListener("mousemove",move);

function move(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    x = event.pageX - c.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - c.offsetTop;
    //Stop all movement
    movingLeft = false;
    movingRight = false;
    movingDown = false;
    movingUp = false;
    
    //Check to see if the mouse is in any area that would change the offset
    if (x>c.width-50) {
        movingLeft = true;
    }
    if (x<50) {
        movingRight = true;   
    }
    if (y<50) {
        movingUp = true;   
    }
    if (y>c.height-50) {
        movingDown = true;   
    }
}

function updateDraw() {
    //draw arrow indicating current x
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(c.width/2-10,0);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width/2+10,0);
    ctx.lineTo(c.width/2,10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.textAlign="center";
    var displayX = c.width/2+offSetX;
    ctx.fillText("x: "+displayX,c.width/2,20);

    //draw arrow indicating current y
    ctx.moveTo(0,c.height/2-10);
    ctx.lineTo(0,c.height/2+10);
    ctx.lineTo(10,c.height/2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.textAlign="left";
    var displayY = c.height/2+offSetY;
    ctx.fillText("y: "+displayY,13,c.height/2+3);
    
    //add a ball and a rectangle just to have a visual of the field of vision actually moving
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.width/2-offSetX,c.height/2-offSetY,30,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillRect(c.width/2+100-offSetX,150-offSetY,50,100);
    
    
    //update the offsets depending on mouse position.
    if (movingLeft) {offSetX++;}
    if (movingRight) {offSetX--;}
    if (movingDown) {offSetY++;}
    if (movingUp) {offSetY--;}
    
    
    requestAnimationFrame(updateDraw);
}

//Starting the whole thing
updateDraw();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```